# Unable to resolve modules: "angular2-meteor/build/meteor_component"

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a project using meteor.js and Angular2.

This is how my package.json looks:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",
"angular2-meteor": "^0.5.6",
"angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.1.1",
"angulartics2": "^1.1.1",

//more dependencies...
```

}

After installing dependencies with `meteor npm install` and then launching app with `meteor` I get errors:

[image]

off course I tried `meteor npm install --save angular2-meteor`, but I get same error.

Then I read somewhere to update node and npm, I did I have tried with node 5*, 6* and latest npm. But I still get error with Angular2 dependencies.

Comment: Could you please show us the `offer-detail.component.js` file ?

Comment: @JeanMel, it is a Typescrite file this is the **compiled js**: http://pastebin.com/TZamPu46 and the original **typescript file**: http://pastebin.com/vZinXrgF

Comment: Thank you. Did you try to import `MeteorComponent` from `angular2-meteor` like this : `import {MeteorComponent} from "angular2-meteor";` ?